# SonarQube : Bugs & Vulnerabilities 0 Code Smells 0

Tags: security, sonarqube

I use SonarQube 6.0, with the plugin sonar-cxx-plugin 0.9.7 (community) and sonar-scanner 2.8, but when I execute it only the information about numbers of lines and duplication. Bugs and Vulnerabilities and code smells is 0. I modified rules bu default used to include MISRA rules (this profile is used well)

I execute sonar by the following command :

```
sonar-scanner -e -Dsonar.host.url=XXX -Dsonar.language=c++ -Dsonar.sources=./ -Dsonar.projectKey=YYY -Dsonar.projectName=TEST
```

I cannot copy the log of the execution, but in here is the information which seem to me the most important (if ever is needed more detail I shall indicate you what you wish to see)

```
main.c:1] cannot find the source for "#include <iostream>"
undefined report path 'sonar.cxx.rats.reportPath'
undefined report path 'sonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath'
undefined report path 'sonar.cxx.pclint.reportPath'
undefined report path 'sonar.cxx.drmemory.reportPath'
undefined report path 'sonar.cxx.compiler.reportPath'
undefined report path 'sonar.cxx.veron.reportPath'
undefined report path 'sonar.cxx.valgrind.reportPath'
Analysis Success
```

As to indicate apparently the analysis is takes place without error, however I always have 0 for Bugs Vulnerabilities and Code Smells in 0.

Would know you how I can adjust it concerns please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `sonar.sources=.`  ( without / )